# Using setup_params() in a ggplot2 geom

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggproto

I'm working on making my own geom for ggplot2, and I've noticed that in ggplot2's documentation, it explicitly says that there is no `setup_params()` for geoms:

> Compared to `Stat` and `Position`, `Geom` is a little different because the execution of the setup and compute functions is split up. `setup_data` runs before position adjustments, and `draw_layer()` is not run until render time, much later. This means there is no `setup_params` because it's hard to communicate the changes.

However, when I make a ggproto Geom that has `setup_params = function(data, params) {...}`, it calls that function fine, and it seemingly works.

What gives? Can I use this function to modify parameters or not?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. It's hard to guess how exactly you might be using your geom at this point.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use it just fine, the methods were added in ggplot2 3.3.0 and it's use was advertised in their NEWS.md file. It was added in https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/pull/3509 in an effort to improve consistency in ggproto classes.

Like you I find the documentation on this a bit confusing, but it was probably overlooked when adding the new `setup_params()`. It would probably make sense to open an issue at the ggplot2 github to document this new(er) use of `setup_params()`.